# Not able to pass index through to child component in react.js

Tags: reactjs, components

I have this "cardComponent" variable in my parent component. It is passing information from a database to my child component (InfoCard) based on the user input of "drinkChoice".

```
  let cardComponents = drinks.map((drink, index) =>{
    if (drink.type === drinkChoice || drinkChoice === 'All') {
      return (<InfoCard drinks={this.state.drinks} i ={ index } />)
    } 
    if (drinkChoice === 'Favorites' && drink.favorite === true) {
      return (<InfoCard drinks={this.state.drinks} i ={ index } />)
    }
    else {
      return console.log("Nothing to report")
    }   })
```

In my child component I want to render in the info specific to each drink.

```
export default function InfoCard(props, i) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className= {classes.root}>
        title = { props.drinks[i].name }
    </Card>
```

If I consolelog a specific index ( console.log(props.drinks[1].name) for example ) it works. But when I try and use index I get the error

TypeError: props.drinks[i] is undefined

I'm pretty sure this is some kind of silly syntax issue i'm overlooking but it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

React functional components take only a single argument, `props`. You've defined your component to take an extra one it'll never receive.

It should be:

```
export default function InfoCard(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { drinks, i } = props;

  return (
    <Card className= {classes.root}>
      title = { drinks[i].name }
    </Card>
  );
}
```

or using object destructuring in function signature

```
export default function InfoCard({ drinks, i }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className= {classes.root}>
      title = { drinks[i].name }
    </Card>
  );
}
```

An improved API may be to just pass the title as a prop instead.

parent

```
<InfoCard title={this.state.drinks[index].name} />
```

child

```
export default function InfoCard({ title }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className= {classes.root}>
      title = { title }
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: Drew, thank you very much for responding. When I try your solution it tells then tells me "props are not defined". Any suggestions?

I'll need that index for other data as well so I don't want to just tie it to title- but I will keep that API suggestion in mind for future situations.

Comment: @kev In my solution I did the object destructuring of props right in the function signature. If you do this as well, then `props` *would* be undefined. Difference is `props.drinks[i].name` and `drinks[i].name`. I'll update answer to show both.